# Why has a comma separated two sentences?

Tags: punctuation

> The West Bengal government has also informed various institutes that once the NOC has been issued, they will not entertain any complaints regarding any negative effect on the intern’s ongoing education.

[Source](https://www.telegraphindia.com/edugraph/news/west-bengal-announces-student-internship-scheme-for-2022/cid/1849933)

Why has a comma been used here to separate two sentences?

Comment: There are not two separate sentences here; the sentence is basically "The West Bengal government has informed various institutes that they will not entertain any complaints."  If you think there are two separate sentences, what are the subject and main verb in each one?

Comment: The comma breaks up a very long sentence to make it easier to read and understand. I think I would have used another one before _once_.

Answer (score 3):

By "sentence," you probably mean an independent clause. Only a coordinating conjunction such as "and" or "but" can join independent clauses, and this sentence does not contain any of those.

However, there is no problem, because there is only one independent clause here:

> The West Bengal government has also informed various institutes

The clauses that follow are dependent. It might be difficult to see them clearly because one contains the other. So I will show them separately:

> 1. that . . . they will not entertain any complaints regarding any negative effect on the intern’s ongoing education
> 2. once the NOC has been issued

#1 is a noun clause. It is the direct object of the verb **informed** in the independent clause.

#2 is an adverb clause. The word **once** is a subordinating conjunction in this sentence, not a counting word. Its meaning is very close to **when**.